# What is the maximum amount of ore a miner can mine per second?

Tags: allegiance

What is the maximum amount of ore a miner can mine per second?  Also, what is the value for normal factions and factions w/ faster mining like Technoflux?

Comment: What game are you talking about here?

Comment: As the tag suggests, [Allegiance](www.freeallegiance.org)

Comment: So what you're asking is... how much ore can a miner mine when a miner can mine ore?  8 D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default miner speed is 1 ore/second.  TF mines at 2 ore/second.